# How to install iptables in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, networking, partitioning, upgrade, security

I tried to install the Linux firewall iptable but it did not work I tried

```
sudo apt-get install iptable
```

and that did not work.

Comment: it is iptables and should alresdy be insalled.

Comment: please copy and paste the error message into your question

Comment: @bodhi.zazen it isn't always installed on some VPS images, etc.  Sometimes it has to be installed manually, even though the underlying kernel netfilter stuff exists.

Comment: It can't find the package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That package name is `iptables` not `iptable`  use command :

```
sudo apt-get install iptables
```